# Highlight Row wxgrid

Tags: python, model-view-controller, grid, wxpython

I was looking for some solutions but i didn't get with it.

I want to highlight the rows in a wx.Grid, when a date is over.

is there any function that can do that?

```
<i>        
def load_grid_fare (self, fares):
   for i, j, k in fares :
      self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,0,str(i.fare_id))
        self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,1,str(j.service_name).encode('utf8'))
        self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,2,str(k.vehicle_type_name).encode('utf8'))
        self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,3,str(i.fare_cash))
        self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,4,str(i.fare_startdate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
        self.grid_fare.SetCellValue(count_rows,5,str(i.fare_enddate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
        count_rows += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the wxPython demo which can be downloaded from the wxPython website. In it there are several examples that show how to change cell, row or column colors. In the demo, it shows that you need to create a GridCellAttr() object and do the following:

```
attr = wx.grid.Grid.GridCellAttr()
attr.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
self.SetRowAttr(5, attr)
```

Where "self" is referring to wx.grid.Grid. The code above will set the 6th row's background color to Red.

Comment: Thank you, I search for some code in the demo folder and found out with the solutions